# "X Location" f-curve name and buttons disappeared

Tags: animation, keyframes, properties, fcurves

I'm working on a blender file. Some time in the last days something changed. Under the active bone's tree in the F-Curve window there are the names and some buttons associated to the f-curves of the action affecting that bone. I have, for example, X Location, Y Location, Z Location (if I inserted location into a keyframe). The problem is, X Location no longer show its name. Neither can I lock or disable that precise f-curve. I can, however, edit the keyframes of that fcurve.

Here is an image illustrating what I mean. All bones in the armature are affected this way and don't show X Location name.

[image]

By the way, in the properties tab of the F-Curve view, when I select the X Location curve, it states correctly its data path (i.e.: pose.bones["toeCtrl_L"].location, RNA Array index 0).

Any cues about how to fix or avoid this?

Comment: I'm truly shocked. The issue solved itself when I started working in another action. I don't consider this a real solution, so I leave the question unanswered for the chance that someone who really knows what's going on appears.

Comment: This appears to be a bug and so should be reported to the [bug tracker instead](https://developer.blender.org/maniphest/task/create/?project=2&type=Bug)